# I have an input text field for mysql. So how can i output the json table from database through ajax?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'index.php',
    data: {val1},
    dataType: 'json',                        
    success: function(response) {
        for(i=0;i<response.length;i++) {
            var test = response[i];

            $("#demo").append(test);
            console.log(test);
            //$("demo").append(test[i]);
        }
        console.log(response);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ur site, if u call "index.php", you get your json array correctly? 
if yes, in the "index.php" page did you set the header to output a json type text, like that

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'");
```

?
Otherwise the result page will be a normal text/html page, so your val(1) wouldn't be recognized like a json string.

If this doesn't work please try to post your "index.php" page

Comment: I have an table in my database with id, name, lastname, adress columns. My val1 is an sql input like "SELECT id, name FROM popis" and i wanna to show then just id and name column but not like this "$("#demo").html(test.id + ' ' + test.name);, i made this without json but i wanna do it now with json. Im new in this so i dont understand that so good.

Comment: In the function you use to retrieve data from your DB, you can use a code like 
`header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'"); 
echo json_encode($return_arr);`
so the result in the page is a json array, that can be recognized from your previus script like json datatype, otherwise without the header your ajax script recognize the index.php return value like a normal string